# Arduino Due Pinout with Explanations?

Tags: pins, arduino-due

I am trying to understand what each pin on my Arduino Due is and what it is used for, and so I have been searching for things like "*Arduino Due pinout*", "*Arduino Due pin mapping*" and similar.

The best I could find was [this table](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMappingSAM3X), however it doesn't help you out at all if you are completely new to electronics and have no idea what `TX2`, `SDA` or `NPCSO` mean, etc.

Does anybody know of Arduino/Due documentation that explains what each I/O pin is?

Comment: Yes, it's called the datasheet for the chip on the board. TX2 is UART 2 Transmit. SDA is I2C **S**erial **DA**ta.  NPSC0 is Chip Select 0 for SPI  (the N is "Not", or "Active Low").

Comment: Thanks @Majenko - is [this](http://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Due-schematic.pdf) what you're talking about?

Comment: That is a start - you can use it in conjunction with this: http://www.atmel.com/images/doc11057s.pdf

Comment: Check out:
http://www.robgray.com/temp/Due-pinout.svg
OR http://www.robgray.com/temp/Due-pinout.pdf
Search 'Due Pinout'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino Due is backed by an Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 microprocessor and most of the pins on the Due are connected directly to this chip. Therefore, you can refer directly to the chip's datasheet for descriptions of these hardware features.

[Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: I'm shocked that something as mainstream as Arduino hasn't incorporated this into their end user docs. But thanks!